# In sympy, how to compose differential operators and invoke the product rule?

Tags: sympy

For example, an operator `dhat`, defined as `dhat(f)(x) = diff(f(x), x) = f'(x)`, composed with `xhat`, defined as `xhat(f)(x) = x*f(x)`, should give:

```
dhat.compose(xhat)(f)(x) = dhat(xhat(f))(x) = diff(x * f(x), x) = f(x) + x * f'(x).
```

So, `dhat.compose(xhat) = identity + xhat * dhat`.

How do I get sympy to figure this out?

```
from sympy.physics.quantum.operator import *
dhat = DifferentialOperator(diff(f(x), x))
xhat = ??
dhat.??(xhat) # There's no "compose" method, so what do I do instead?
```

Comment: have you explored `sympy.Function`?

Answer (score 0):

In an `isympy` session:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)

In [1]: (f(x)*g(x)).diff(x)
Out[1]: 
     d               d       
f(x)⋅──(g(x)) + g(x)⋅──(f(x))
     dx              dx      

In [2]: f(g(x)).diff(x)
Out[2]: 
  d            d       
─────(f(g(x)))⋅──(g(x))
dg(x)          dx
```